# Docker private registry status in "Restarting (1)" Forever

Tags: linux, ssl, docker, registry, devops

I have setup a docker private registry with using registry:2 image in OEL6 using below command.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name bkdevregistry -v /var/lib/docker/certs/:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/xx.yy.com.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/xx.yy.com.key registry:2
```

I have followed the official guide to create the certificates and setting up the registry.

The system got rebooted due to maintenance activities and after rebooting, the registry container is not working at all. It's immediately going to the `Restarting (1)` status and is not changing its status.

```
[root@slcn09vmf0022 ~]# docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                    NAMES
44ad9d09d210        registry:2          "/bin/registry /etc/d"   9 minutes ago       Restarting (1) 3 minutes ago   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   blkdevreg
```

Any suggestion to bring it to normal will be appreciated.

The log:

```
time="2016-05-18T15:29:34Z" level=fatal msg="open : no such file or directory"
time="2016-05-18T17:18:47Z" level=warning msg="No HTTP secret provided - generated random secret. This may cause problems with uploads if multiple registries are behind a load-balancer. To provide a shared secret, fill in http.secret in the configuration file or set the REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET environment variable." go.version=go1.5.3 instance.id=7034ae26-a1e8-4bc4-828a-be38d17a7ebb version=v2.3.1
time="2016-05-18T17:18:47Z" level=info msg="redis not configured" go.version=go1.5.3 instance.id=7034ae26-a1e8-4bc4-828a-be38d17a7ebb version=v2.3.1
time="2016-05-18T17:18:47Z" level=info msg="Starting upload purge in 51m0s" go.version=go1.5.3 instance.id=7034ae26-a1e8-4bc4-828a-be38d17a7ebb version=v2.3.1
time="2016-05-18T17:18:47Z" level=info msg="using inmemory blob descriptor cache" go.version=go1.5.3 instance.id=7034ae26-a1e8-4bc4-828a-be38d17a7ebb version=v2.3.1
```

Comment: `docker logs container_id` will show you the error message.

Comment: @warmoverflow, this is the message that is repeated in the log:

Comment: You did not post the message..

Comment: level=fatal msg="open : no such file or directory",level=warning msg="No HTTP secret provided - generated random secret. This may cause problems with uploads if multiple registries are behind a load-balancer. To provide a shared secret, fill in http.secret in the configuration file or set the REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET environment variable." go.version=go1.5.3 instance.id=7034ae26-a1e8-4bc4-828a-be38d17a7ebb version=v2.3.1,evel=info msg="redis not configured" go.version=go1.5.3 instance.id=7034ae26-a1e8-4bc4-828a-be38d17a7ebb version=v2.3.1,...... This is the message .. with timestamp removed ...

Comment: In my case, I added `-v` thinking "verbose debug output" and that's not what `-v` is for. :facepalm:

Answer (score 2):

try delete docker registry  and restart docker service  and iptables, then rerun  docker private registry with using registry:2 ,use docker logs container_id to see the error repeated in the log

Answer (score 1):

> docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name bkdevregistry -v
>   /var/lib/docker/certs/:/certs -e
>   REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/xx.yy.com.crt -e
>   REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/xx.yy.com.key registry:2

The problem is due to incorrect use of `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE` environment variable for both CERT and KEY as well.

For key use `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY`